# Dynamic Object Creation

Tags: javascript, dynamic, object

I have a function that takes a string object name and I need the function to create an new instance of a object that has the same name as the value of the string

For example,

```
function Foo(){}
function create(name){
    return new name();
}
create('Foo'); //should be equivalent to new Foo();
```

While I know this would be possible via eval, it would be good to try and avoid using it. I am also interested if anyone has an alternative ideas to the problem (below)

---

I have a database and a set of (using classical OO methodology) classes, roughly one for each table that define common operations on that table. (Very similar to Zend_Db for those who use PHP). As everything is asynchronous doing tasks based on the result of the last one can lead to very indented code

```
var table1 = new Table1Db();
table1.doFoo({
    success:function(){
        var table2 = new Table2Db();
        table2.doBar({
            notFound:function(){
                doStuff();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The obvious solution is to create helper methods that abstracts the asynchronous nature of the code.

```
Db.using(db) //the database object
  .require('Table1', 'doFoo', 'success') //table name, function, excpected callback
  .require('Table2', 'doBar', 'notFound')
  .then(doStuff);
```

Which simplifies things. However the problem is that I need to be able to create the table classes, the names of which can be inferred from the first augment passed to `require` which leads me to the problem above...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply pass the constructor function into the `require` method?  That way you sidestep the whole issue of converting from name to function.  Your example would then look like:

```
Db.using(db) //the database object
  .require(Table1Db, 'doFoo', 'success') //table constructor, function name, expected callback
  .require(Table2Db, 'doBar', 'notFound')
  .then(doStuff);
```

However, if you really want to use a string...

Why are you deadset on avoiding using `eval`?  It is a tool in the language and every tool has its purpose (just as every tool can be misused).  If you're concerned about allowing arbitrary execution, a simple regular expression test should render your usage safe.

If you're dead-set on avoiding `eval` and if all of your constructor functions are created in the default global scope (i.e. the window object), this would work:

```
function create(name) {
  return new window[name]();
}
```

If you want to get fancy and support namespace objects (i.e. `create('MyCompany.MyLibrary.MyObject')`, you could do something like this:

```
function create(name) {
  var current,
      parts,
      constructorName;

  parts = name.split('.');
  constructorName = parts[parts.length - 1];
  current = window;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
    current = current[parts[i]];
  }

  return new current[constructorName]();
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the response. As always after looking over an answer I feel a bit stupid for having missed some (in retrospect fairly obvious) things. In this case, strings are easier, however passing the constructor (something I didn't know could be done in that way) looks lightly neater and more importantly clear. I am not dead set against the use of eval, and as you say it has its place, however experience has taught me that if I think I need to use it 99% of the time I don't understand the language well enough. (This is one of those times).

Comment: @Yacoby well said! :) Especially the last sentences. I wish everyone would think this way.

Comment: This was a great answer. Learned something new about javascript! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You were at the gate of completeness. While Annabelle's solution let's you to do what's you've just wanted in the way you wanted *(passing strings)*, let me offer you an alternative. *(passing function references)*

```
function Foo(){}
function create(name){
    return new name();
}
create(Foo); // IS equivalent to new Foo();
```

And **voila, it works** :) I told you. You were at the doorsteps of the solution.

What happened is that you've try to do this

```
new 'Foo'()
```

Which doesn't makes much sense, does it? But now you pass the function by reference so the line `return new name();` will be transformed into `return new Foo();` just how you would expect.

And now the doors are opened to abstract the asynchronousness of your application. Have fun!

Appendix: **Functions are first-class objects**, which means that they can be stored by reference, passed as an argument by reference or returned by another function as values.

Comment: The second and third parameters to `require()` still have to be strings, the objects they identify are properties of objects that do not exist yet.