# Javascript object instantiation similar to php new $className();

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm trying to do the equivalent to this but in JS.

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$obj = new $className();
```

I've tried obvious things but with no luck, currently resorted to using eval as below :/

```
eval('var model = ' + modelName + '();');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For global "classes", use:

```
var classname = "Date";
var obj = new window[classname]();
```

`window` is the global namespace. Variables and methods defined immediately within `<script>`, without a wrapper are automatically stored in the global namespace.

For methods of other "namespaces", use:

```
var classname = "round";
var obj = new Math[funcname]();
// Illustrative purposes only, Math doesn't need `new`
```

For private methods which aren't attached to a namespace, there's no solution except for eval or Function:

```
var classname = "nonglobal";
var obj = new (Function(classname))();
```

You should avoid `eval` whenever possible, especially if you're working with unknown strings.

Answer (score 1):

See this SO question for a good anwser: [Dynamic Object Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216892/dynamic-object-creation)

But basically you want `return new window[modelName];`